# How to make camel websocket client listening on the server port? not connecting to server port through url in route of camel client

Tags: websocket, apache-camel

client side route - from("websocket://localhost:9999/camel/chat")

where jetty server of websocket server application is running on 9999.. and when trying to connect through jetty websocket client application, it starts another jetty on same port which is in the above route and gives address already in use exception.. how should i make a connection through camel client..

Answer (score 0):

[Websocket component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/websocket-component.html) starts embedded jetty server. To utilize servlet in existing container, you need to use [Atmosphere websocket component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/atmosphere-websocket-component.html).

> The component uses the SERVLET component and uses the Atmosphere library to support the Websocket transport in various Servlet containers (e..g., Jetty, Tomcat, …​).
>
> Unlike the Websocket component that starts the embedded Jetty server, this component uses the servlet provider of the container.